# Cant turn off sound player when new navigation controller is pushed

Tags: xcode, ios5, object, avaudioplayer

Im playing a audio that can be turned  on and off with the following

IBAction //play audio

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Apptrack.mp3"];
NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
NSError* err;

//Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

if( err ){

    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    //set our delegate and begin playback
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //(for continuous loop use -1, or any number for number of loops)
    player.currentTime = 1;
    player.volume = .5;

}
```

IBAction to turn off sound player: //stop audio

```
 [player stop];
```

When I push to another view controler and come back again, the button no longer works to stop the audio and it constantly runs (the loop is about 3 mins long).  So then I tried added this to the above code:

```
 if ([self.player isPlaying] == YES) {
     [self.player stop];
    } else {
     [self.player play];
    }
```

Still nothing, maybe someone more experienced in programming could point my in the direction of what im doing wrong?

Comment: Just to update this is only an issue if the audio is playing as the next view is pushed.  Ive put `[player stop];` in the viewdidload in an attempt to stop the audio playing when navigating back to the original  view controller but still nothing? For some reason once the audio is playing and the next navigation controller is loaded it refuses to respond to the `player stop` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a work around I added `[player stop];` to the IBAction of the button pushing to the next view controller